# Export List to XML using workflow?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow2013

Is it possible to export SharePoint 2013 List to an XML file?
I want to create site based on my own GUI (HTML, CSS and jQuery) and i need to show content of Document library's. I already used  workflows to create list of files, now i want to export this list to xml and used this xml file as data source to create list of files in my div.

I was thinking about refreshing XML file every time when a new item will be added to the list, and using for this purpose workflow.

I do not know if this is a good idea, but the only one I have.

Is this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marek Sarad said, working in XML is not a good idea. In case you still want to use XML, you can go with SharePoint REST API which provide the data by default in atom+XML format unless you specify "application/json;odata=verbose" as Accept type. Simply try using the following URL, which will give you data in run time.

```
http://<your_site>/sites/<your_site_coll>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<Title_of_List>')/Items
```

This REST end point will give you all the items in a List/Library in XML format.

Comment: Thank You very much for your solution :) I already used in my case and works like charm :)

Comment: Welcome dear :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't export and import. Better to do it real time. Sharepoint has build in web services you could query. (check the list.asmx) or you can use client object model. Gary Lapointe has a good article that should put you on the right path: https://www.itunity.com/article/connecting-spo-csom-api-powershell-1038